# JavaScript Executor working in Google Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

So I am using Selenium tests to test my website across multiple browsers.

The tests that I made work completely fine for Google Chrome however, it does not work for Firefox.

```
public class BrowserAutomationTest {
    private final static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    private final static Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    private final static JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver");

        final ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

        driver.get("file:/graph.html");
    }

@Test
private void leftClickAddNodeTest() {
    //add two nodes in different positions by left clicking
    final WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("tour-close-button")));
driver.findElement(By.className("tour-close-button")).click();

builder.moveByOffset(0, 0)
        .click()
        .moveByOffset(100, 100)
        .click()
        .build()
        .perform();

final ArrayList<Object> jsReturnObject = (ArrayList<Object>) js.executeScript("return sigmaInstance"); // Error is here
assertTrue(jsReturnObject.size() == 2);
}
}
```

So the above code works completely fine with Google Chrome.

However when replacing the Webdriver line to this:

```
private final static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Firefox does load up however when js.executeScript() is called it returns an exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: sigmaInstance is not defined
```

The strange issue is that this error does not occur in Selenium Google Chrome test. Also, when inserting the JS manually to the Firefox browser, it will work.

What could be the issue? Thanks

EDIT: Full Stack Trace

```
objc[3179]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1088bb4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10893f4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
1525869916907   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.20.1
1525869916913   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:22235
1525869917264   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin" "-marionette" "-profile" "/var/folders/sn/b7mx42_530v_kx2xqn27d84h0000gn/T/rust_mozprofile.VRXA2ZSTKOIA"
1525869917876   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
2018-05-09 13:45:18.710 plugin-container[3182:399742] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x7c3f, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2018-05-09 13:45:18.859 plugin-container[3182:399742] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x7cbb, name = 'com.apple.coredrag'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
1525869919046   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 60700
1525869919134   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
May 09, 2018 1:45:19 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
2018-05-09 13:45:19.607 plugin-container[3183:399823] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x7c43, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.
2018-05-09 13:45:19.771 plugin-container[3183:399823] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x190f, name = 'com.apple.coredrag'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: sigmaInstance is not defined
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'Emans-MBP-2', ip: '2a00:23c4:4a09:b00:6cfa:11:c2f:f577', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 59.0.3, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 3181, moz:profile: /var/folders/sn/b7mx42_530v..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 17.4.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: d2b4c7f5-2951-1047-8f97-4a7640091b09

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:482)
    at BrowserAutomationTest.leftClickAddNodeTest(BrowserAutomationTest.java:58)
    at BrowserAutomationTest.testSequence(BrowserAutomationTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

*** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for id: telemetry_modules_ping
```

Comment: It's most likely a side effect of the sandbox executing the script. Instead execute `return (window.wrappedJSObject || window).sigmaInstance`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Tried the line but now it returns null

Comment: If it returns null, then the page has not yet created the variable at the time you are calling `executeScript`

Comment: Interesting. The confusing thing is that when i put a breakpoint and ensure that the application loads (sigmaInstance). It still returns null.

Answer (score 0):

The complete error stack trace would have definitely helped us to debug your error / issue in a better way but this error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: ReferenceError: sigmaInstance is not defined
```

...may be arising because **GeckoDriver** and/or **sigmaInstance** was not properly declared/defined.

First, you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *GeckoDriver* binary as a `String` as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver");
```

Note : As per your current code **geckodriver** is not within `""` to be recognized as a `String`

Second, you are trying to **return sigmaInstance** without executing any **script**. Your call to **`executeScript`** should be in the following format :

```
java.lang.Object executeScript(java.lang.String script, java.lang.Object... args)
```

As per the *Java Docs* [**`executeScript()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) Executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. The script fragment provided will be executed as the body of an anonymous function. Within the script, use document to refer to the current document. Note that local variables will not be available once the script has finished executing, though global variables will persist.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have edited my post to show full stack trace. The GeckoDriver was a typo, sorry. With your explanation of executeScript() why would it work fine with Chrome but not Firefox?